# MP4Box and concatenating files with different aspect ratio

Tags: video, mp4, mp4box

I have a large directory of small video clips taken with a cell phone. I've been able to use mp4box to concatenate them into a single file nicely EXCEPT if they are different aspect ratio. In this case it is when I try to combine a video taken with the phone upright vs. taken side ways.

> mp4box.exe -cat long.mp4 -cat wide.mp4  broken.mp4

mp4box is saying:

> WARNING: Concatenating track ID 1 with different SPS - result file might be brok
>   en

When I play the video it clearly blocky and corrupted.

**Is there a way to merge these files with mp4box or any other command line tool and force a single (probably 16:9) format?**

Also even better, since I am doing this in an automated fashion, it would be nice to have a way to just force all of the output video to a single format rather than have to perform special actions on just the upright videos.

I've tried resetting or forcing the SPS, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible without re-encoding the video. Is that an option?

Comment: Sure I could do that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try recent versions of ffmpeg ([ffmpeg wiki: How to concatenate media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files) ) although you may have to resize the video...